# Extra space when using overflow:hidden in inline-block list

Tags: html, css-position, space, css

Refering to this : http://jsfiddle.net/CZk8L/4/

Can anybody explain to me why the `overflow:hidden` style generates this extra space at the bottom of the first `li` ?

This is driving me crazy for hours.

The fact is I need the `position:relative; overflow:hidden` on my first `li` because of the `form` that I want to hide and move inside it (to follow the cursor).

I tried to set some `height`or `max-height` on each element, but it did not work.
I also tried some `line-height`

A solution to re-align both `li` could be to add the same `position:relative; overflow:hidden` on the second `li`, but it still be the extra space under them and I would like to understand the root cause.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of "display:inline-block" can you use "float:left" Or check this link http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/CZk8L/6/

Comment: Thanks, the `li {float:left}` is efficient ([http://jsfiddle.net/CZk8L/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/CZk8L/8/)). I still do not understand why this space appears with the `display:inline-block`. And your fiddle does not work neither : I want to keep de `overflow:hidden` on the first `li`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `ul` `padding:5px` to `padding:0px` to avoid space under `li`.

```
 ul {display: inline-block; background:#DDD; padding:0px;white-space: nowrap; margin:50px 200px;}
```

You can align the `li` using `vertical-align: top;`

```
   .with_overflow li:first-child {position: relative; overflow: hidden;vertical-align: top; }
    .with_overflow form {position: absolute; opacity: 0;}
    .with_overflow iframe {display:none}
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KCC8t/)

Comment: Hi, it did not work (even on your updated fiddle). The space I want to 'fight' is under the first `li` and not between them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Tkx, but I need to keep `overflow:hidden` in the first `li`

Comment: @M'sieurToph' yes it work with that too. see here http://jsfiddle.net/CZk8L/10/ .. just add vertical-align: top;

Comment: Oooh. Nice move! I tried to re-align the second `li` to the top, but not the first one ... I think I have a winner! Thanks a lot. Can you post your answer? So I can 'check' it! (EDIT : Just put back the ul padding to 5px on your fiddle to be as close from the original fiddle as possible)